# C# Drawing on panel in TLP

Tags: c#

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
  Graphics graphicObj;
  graphicObj = this.CreateGraphics();
  Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 2);

  graphicObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, 200, 200, 200, 200);
 }
```

This work on form. But for auto resizing items such as buttons, label I have to use TablePanelLayout, and drawing on it only works with adding to construtor in form

```
panel1.Paint+=new PaintEventHandler(panel1_draw);
```

and then by drawing with this method

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    Pen myp = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 4);
    Font fy = new Font("Helvetica", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    Brush br = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    g.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fy, br, 0,0);
}
```

Question is Why/what topic should I master to know it.

Comment: `Why/what topic should I master to know it?`  What are you asking?  Is something not working?  Never use CreateGraphics, it's only a temporary canvas.

Comment: I suppose you need to understand the Control.DoubleBuffered property.  Splattering pixels onto the window like you did in the first snippet cannot work when double-buffering is turned on.  Like it is for the Button and Label controls.  Those pixels disappear again when the back-buffer is blitted to the screen, a millisecond later.  Using CreateGraphics() to draw is only ever correct when you don't mind losing the pixels and paint at a very high rate.  Like you'd do in a game.